# DateTime formatting annotations not working with Vue app in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datetime, vue.js, data-annotations

Do data annotations work with a Vue app in Visual Studio?

I have a Vue app with Visual Studio and I'm fetching a DateTime from a entity framework query. I'm using data annotations on the view model like below but it's not getting formatted on the screen.

Any reason why?

part of the entity query

```
var recordsVM = records.Select(r => new GetRecordsReturnViewModel
{
    StartDate = r.StartDate, // DateTime?
    // other params
}
```

viewmodel

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
```

.vue

```
<td><span>{{ props.item.startDate }}</span></td>
```

what I'm seeing in each td

> 1943-09-01T00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing ideas from different platforms.  `DisplayFormatAttribute` can be used by ASP.Net MVC for server-side HTML generation (Razor views, etc.), but it is not something that is exposed to the client.  There's nothing that Vue.js (or any other front-end framework) can do with this.

Instead, use a client-side library to format your dates. Many exist, such as [Date-fns](https://date-fns.org/), [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/), or [Moment](http://momentjs.com/).  Or, you might consider using a library made specifically for Vue, such as [vue-filter-date-format](https://github.com/eduardnikolenko/vue-filter-date-format#readme).

Comment: see the problem I'm havign is just that! Formatting client side, I have two columns start and end date and when the rows are 500  it takes a long time to render. So I'm trying to format the dates in the entity framework query, which I can't get working. So I tried data attributes, but wasn't sure if it was possible

Comment: Long list rendering being slow is a *different* problem.  It's not related to formatting dates.  Virtualization is usually the right way to approach this.  For  example, check out [vue-virtual-scroller](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-virtual-scroller).

Comment: If you really want to change things server side, you wouldn't change anything about EF, but rather how Json.Net was serializing.  For example, you could use a `JsonConverter`.  But it's a bad idea to emit a locale-specific date format from a REST API, so I don't recommend that for your scenario - unless you simply wanted to truncate the time component.